# Android - Switching between Activities and Screens with same xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, class, android-studio

I'm building an app for educational purposes, with a lot of questions and challenges to the user to solve. But, it would be a HUGE amount of screens if I create a lot of questions and one xml file and activity for each one, as I want to have different kinds of questions, where the user should be able to write the code, select a block of code or select the correct answer about theory and stuff. **Is there a way to use the same model of screen(xml file) for one specific kind of question?** Like, using one model to all the screens and questions where the user should select the correct answer, and another model to another kind of question..

p.s: Yes, i'm kind newbie in Android

Thanks! :)

Comment: You can include existing XML using something like `<include layout="@layout/common_helpinfo" ></include>`. You can go even further with Databinding by passing variables. e.g. the above could be `<include layout="@layout/common_helpinfo"         app:tagstr="@{@string/hi_tag_world1}"
                > </include>`. (this is then used in the XML like `android:tag="@{tagstr}"`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using **FragmentStatePagerAdapter**

You only needs one layout and every time a fragment looses focus, it is destroyed automatically.

It is the same as adapters. You just create the visible views and 2 more. In this case you will have the visible question and one on the left and one on the right.

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: by **"you will have the visible question and one on the left and one on the right."** you mean the user would be able to go to the next question and go back to the previous question? Also, does that make impossible to save the current state of the question? Like if the user want to go back to some question and see if he answered it right, would that be possible?

Comment: Do you know how adapters work on android? And yes you can save the answer in the database and put it back if user goes back.

Comment: I know what it is (something for lists, right?), but not how it works

Comment: Let's assume you have 10 questions. Instead of creating 10 questions you are gonna have the current, previous and next question. It's gonna be creating and destroying automatically so you don't waste your ram

Comment: Hmmm okay, I got it now, thanks! I use it with Fragments, right?

Comment: Yes. Google this FragmentStatePagerAdapter. If you don't find anything let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can define all kinds of questions, such as checkboxes, radioButtons, Edittexts and etc. in a xml file and, if necessary, visible or hide them.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to display questions in your activity.

In short, Fragments are mini-Activities with their own layouts, so each different type of question should have a corresponding Fragment. That should be exactly what you need.

For example, you can create a fragment_radiobox and a fragment_codesnippet in your project. In first one you will include a TextView for your question and a few checkboxes for an answer, and in the second one you'd have an EditText field to write some code. You can call any of those two fragments in your main activity depending on which question you want to display.

Comment: So, if the user's answer is correct, it'll take the user to the next question with the same xml model? and I should create these fragments like an activity?